# Jquery onLoad for not existing images now

Tags: jquery, onload-event

I have container with images

```
<div class='container'>
    <img src='...' />
    <img src='...' />
    <img src='...' />
</div>
```

The images are loaded dynamically. Is there way to bind cross-browser (IE7+) onLoad event in 'jQuery-on'-like style, like this (pseudocode):

```
$(element).one('load', 'img', function () {
    // my callback
}).each(function () {
    if (this.complete || image.naturalWidth > 0) $(this).load();
});
```

Comment: in the doc : http://api.jquery.com/load-event/ 1st example : trigger an event when an image is loaded ;)

Comment: This example doesn't work for cached images in IE7, and then I must call $(this).load() manually

Comment: You mean that `$(".container img").load(function(){...};` doesn't fire ??

Comment: Your example is about static elements. With dinamically added images `$(".container img").load(function(){...};` will be fire if you bind this after adding. I'm interesting way to bind load event for non-existing images now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attaching an event handler to the container will not work in this case, since the image load event does not bubble. (If you're into reading specification documents, the HTML spec says that the [image load event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element) is a "[simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event)" — which is a type of event that does not bubble.)

Instead, you must attach the handler individually to each dynamically loaded image, like so:

```
// Add an image dynamically
$("<img/>")

    // Attach the load handler individually to each image being loaded
    .load(onLoad)

    .attr("src", "http://placekitten.com/" + width + "/" + height)
    .appendTo($(".container"));
```

A functioning example: http://jsfiddle.net/dmillz/ZmFfv/